# In PHP :how can I use include() Function which parameter is variable?

Tags: php, function, include

I need to use include Function with variable.

but,when I try to do it I faced some errors .

Code :

```
$year=$_POST['year'];

$month=$_POST['month'];

$day=$_POST['day'];

include "Event.php?year=".$year."&month=".$month."&day=".$day;
```

so,can U help me ? : )

Comment: What are you trying to do with `include`?

Comment: I don't get it either. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 4):

When you include files, you can't pass them any arguments. However they DO inherit any variables in the current scope (global or method).

I'm guessing at what your code does, but I assume you can just do this:

`include "Event.php";`

Comment: thanks dear Coronatus .
but ,your Suggestion it doesn't work : ( 

the main code I wrote it , to make a calender .
therefore  ,I need to do this with include to refresh every add new event in specific day .

Comment: yes I also think that it should do the work. If it's not working, then that means something is wrong with your code. If you don't have any copyright problems or such, please post your relevant code, so that others can view & understand what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to use that kind of sintax.
The $year, $month and $day variables will be perfectly visible and accessible on the Event.php file.

To get along with what you want, check PHP manual on http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php to see some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I have a couple of guesses handy.

1 - You are trying to redirect the user, with those parameters appended to the url, in which case you will probably need to utilise [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header("Location: http://example.com/Event.php?year=$year&month=$month&day=$day");
```

2 - You are trying to capture the output of that page given the presence of certain GET parameters, in which case you can utilise [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$output = file_get_contents("http://localhost/Event.php?year=$year&month=$month&day=$day");
```

Comment: yes ,
your  First  guesses is exactly what i want to do ,

but ,it does not work with me 
can U tell me how ?

Comment: @Nina - what exactly happens. You *cannot* redirect *after* sending any output to the browser, so no echo statements, nothing.

Comment: this is not exactly right. We can at least output any data to browser first & then use the header function, but with one condition - you must use the function "ob_start()" at the very second line of your page where you are outputting the data to browser. The first line will be the PHP start tag "<?php" & no use of any whitespace character other than the use of "enter" in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Include the Event.php directly and access the $_POST or $_GET variables from there.

```
include('Event.php');

// Event.php:
echo $_POST['year']; // works
```